# Swipe UITableViewCell and trigger action automatically without pressing action button

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here's the **leadingSwipeAction** on **UITableViewCell**. My question is how to trigger `delete` action by just swiping and without clicking on the actual button that appears on the left side.

**VERY IMPORTANT:** I don't want to use method `actions.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = YES;` . I want to trigger action automatically just on a first stage 1/3 screen swipe.

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UIContextualAction *delete = [UIContextualAction 
contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleNormal title:nil 
handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull 
sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
    
    // your code...
    
    }];
    delete.image  = [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"trash"];

    UISwipeActionsConfiguration *actions = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:delete, nil]];

    actions.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = NO;

    return actions;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Swiping to ~80% of the screen width should cause the action to fire without requiring the additional tap. I don't think you need additional code changes.

Comment: No. That's not how WhatsApp Reply to Message action works. Over here I can swipe like 30% and it already triggers action. I need 30% - 50%. Nobody is swiping 80%.

Comment: If you want that specific behavior, you're going to need to utilities a completely custom implementation then, you can't utilize the default behavior for `UITableView`'s `UISwipeActionConfiguration`.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on that you might know?